# Webpack is not watching errors when compiled

Tags: typescript, webpack

Problem: If I have typescript erros, Webpack is not watching it

Webpack compils even if typecript types erros occures

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have tried the latest version of [webpack5](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/)

Comment: the problem is still occuruing...

Comment: apparently you didn't provide enough information for us helping you. Do you have a reproducible repo or adding the `webpack.config` and the entry point point?